# Should we always keep same value for body {font-size:...} which we want to use content <p>?

Tags: css, xhtml

What are pros and cons to define font-size for body?

what if somewhere i will need font smaller and bigger than body?

will i get body font size (12px) + needed font size for `<p>` (10px)  = 22

Should we always keep same value for `body` font size which we want to use content paragraph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It's good to define a global value, that changes relatively (em) or absolutely (px) when needed.
2. No, the pixel values won't add up. However, if `body` is defined as `12px` and `p` is defined as `2em` (a relative unit), then `p` will be `24px`.
3. Again, it's good to define base globals so values are easier to predict.

Answer (score 0):

I defined it right in the body, and just override it by tag or class where appropriate. I don't see any problem defining a "default" font-size on the body.

Comment: Should we always keep same value for body font size which we want to use content paragraph?

Comment: Not necessarily. For example, your `body` might set as 16px, while `p` content paragraphs are defined as `0.75em` (equating to `12px`) - as you want long text passages to be slightly smaller.

Comment: @Delan Azabani - Then if we will define different sizes for all elements after body then what is the benefit to define font-size for body. is it just to make global control?